# How to test my paid app for Google TV

Tags: android, google-play, google-tv

I have developed a World Time App (paid app) for Google TV and wanted to install it on my Google TV. How do i install it on my TV without paying for it.

Comment: is it really that expensive? aren't you just paying into your own pocket? im willing to bet it's cheap and the time you spent posting this would have cost more money than just buying it.

Comment: Its not about the money, but about whether that feature exists and i am not aware of it.

Comment: BTW: I tried buying my own app and it does not allow buying your own app. So the only way to test it is to install it via adb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install it through the market without paying for it, I don't know of a way to do that.

Otherwise, you can use `adb` to connect and install your apk using the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_debug